# What does the @ prefix do on string literals in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, syntax, literals

I read some C# article to combine a path using `Path.Combine`(part1,part2).

It uses the following:

```
string part1 = @"c:\temp";
string part2 = @"assembly.txt";
```

May I know what is the use of `@` in part1 and part2?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`@` is not related to any method.

It means that you don't need to escape special characters in the string following to the symbol:

```
@"c:\temp"
```

is equal to

```
"c:\\temp"
```

Such string is called 'verbatim' or @-quoted. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 29):

As other have said its one way so that you don't need to escape special characters and very useful in specifying file paths.

```
string s1 =@"C:\MyFolder\Blue.jpg";
```

One more usage is when you have large strings and want it to be displayed across multiple lines rather than a long one.

```
string s2 =@"This could be very large string something like a Select query
which you would want to be shown spanning across multiple lines 
rather than scrolling to the right and see what it all reads up";
```

Answer (score 14):

As stated in [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e):

> 2.4.4.5 String literals
>
> C# supports two forms of string
>   literals: regular string literals and
>   verbatim string literals. A regular
>   string literal consists of zero or
>   more characters enclosed in double
>   quotes, as in "hello", and may include
>   both simple escape sequences (such as
>   \t for the tab character), and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences. A verbatim string literal
>   consists of an @ character followed by
>   a double-quote character, zero or more
>   characters, and a closing double-quote
>   character. A simple example is
>   @"hello". In a verbatim string
>   literal, the characters between the
>   delimiters are interpreted verbatim,
>   the only exception being a
>   quote-escape-sequence. In particular,
>   simple escape sequences, and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in
>   verbatim string literals.

Answer (score 6):

It denotes a verbatim string literal, and allows you to use certain characters that normally have special meaning, for example `\`, which is normally an escape character, and new lines. For this reason it's very useful when dealing with Windows paths.

Without using `@`, the first line of your example would have to be:

```
string part1 = "c:\\temp";
```

More information [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3a_What_is_a_verbatim_string_literal).

Answer (score 3):

The @ just indicates a different way of specifying a string such that you do not have to escape characters with . the only caveat is that double quotes need to be "" to represent a single ".

Answer (score 2):

With @ you dont have to escape special characters.

So you would have to write "c:\\temp" without @

If more presise it is called 'verbatim' strings. You could read here about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If that URL fails, try this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim