# How to generate path of a file residing on another computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, path

I load data from a Database on another PC in local network , and it works perfectly fine.

I just enter server name and db path and it works.

Now i am also looking for latest modified file in the folder on the server ,it works fine on local pc but when i use a server name  plus path , it generate that path concatenated with the executable folder path.

```
string tmpPath=string.Empty;
if (serverName != "")
  {
   tmpPath = "\\" + serverName + "\\" + TrackingPath + "\\u00" + ID;
  }
```

And after this i simply read the folder to get latest modified file.

But the path becomes  ....Debug\servername\trackingpath..... which is wrong.

**EXAMPLE**

```
Servename=testServer
TrackingPath= TmpFolder\SharedFolder\TrackingFolder
```

So according to my code it should become  `\\testServer\\TmpFolder\SharedFolder\TrackingFolder` but instead it make it   `project....\Debug\\\testServer\\TmpFolder\SharedFolder\TrackingFolder`
So how can i read this folder from testserver

Comment: We need more details. Is this when debugging? What's `serverName`? What's `TrackingPath`? Why are you not using Path.Combine? `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx`

Comment: As in, where are the values of `serverName` and `TrackingPath` coming from? Are they being passed in? Where are they set? How are they set? As in, show us the *actual* code where they are set.

Comment: The come from the database they are always serverName = abc and tracking path starting as i stated in example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to work with path files and remember that the backslash is a special character in C# and it is used to escape other chars. So you need

```
string ID = "test";
string TrackingPath = "tracking";
string serverName = "server_name";
string tmpPath=string.Empty;
if (serverName != "")
{
    tmpPath = Path.Combine(@"\\", serverName, TrackingPath ,"u00" + ID);
}
Console.WriteLine(tmpPath);
```

To insert a backslash in a string you need to double it or prefix with the [Verbatim string prefix character `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134547/what-does-the-prefix-do-on-string-literals-in-c)

Using 3.5 Framework and below

```
    tmpPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(@"\\", serverName), TrackingPath) ,"u00" + ID);
```

Well not very efficient but it works

Comment: IT says only 2 arguments can be passed to Path.Combine

Comment: No, check better you could pass an array -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Error 5 No overload for method 'Combine' takes 4 arguments

Comment: i am using ....3.5 Again the issue is not the path is wrong etc  , the issue is it looks for the path inside the debug folder! Where it should use the servername+tracking path.

Comment: That's the problem. Need 4.0, ok you could split in three separate calls

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31338/discussion-between-steve-and-confusedmind)