# C:/Users/... is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("C:\\Users\\Renu\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\matrimony\\App_Data\\images"+filename));
```

Here, PhotoUpload is name of a FileUpload component, filename is a simple string object. the content of PhotoUpload should be saved into the folder named "images" under App_Data folder. but after executing, I get the following error:

> C:/Users/Renu/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/matrimony/App_Data/images

Is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected. I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

A guide on ASP.NET [MapPath](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath).

```
PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\images\"+filename));
```

Where `filename = "myFile.png"`

Using <kbd>@</kbd> to provide a [literal string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134562/1398425).

Comment: PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\images"+filename));

Comment: The you need to grant your website permission to write to the folder.

Comment: Possibly you are missing a trailing \ <- Backslash @"~\App_Data\images\"

Comment: how to do the permission related part??

Comment: what is the exact value of filename?

Comment: `String filename="";
        if (PhotoUpload.PostedFile != null)
        {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(PhotoUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\images"+filename));
            
        }`

Comment: Yes then you need a trailing backslash as in my answer above `PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\images\"+filename));`

Comment: sir, i made the changes.. now it gives this error--Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Renu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\matrimony\App_Data\images\'.

Comment: filename is empty give it a default value `String filename="myImage.png";`

Comment: it worked.. earlier i had retrieved the name of the file uploaded in "filename" but the name was never fetched. is the following line wrong?? filename = Path.GetFileName(PhotoUpload.PostedFile.FileName);

Comment: filename = PhotoUpload.PostedFile.FileName;

Answer (score 0):

write this way:

*** ~ get the path for the website 
i assume that your website path is C:\Users\Renu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010**

```
PhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\images"+filename)));
```

Comment: matrimony is the name of the project.