# How to recognize this character "\" in C#

Tags: c#

I just want to write in Console this "\".

```
Console.Write("\");
```

But it doesn't recognize it like a string or character ,but as a command.

Comment: No, it recognizes it as an escape character. Either use `Console.Write("\\")` or `Console.Write(@"\")`. This is just a matter of string literals.

Comment: It's the one that goes from upper left to lower right. Can't miss it.

Comment: If there is nothing in your string to escape (ie. you want the literal value inside the double quotes) then prefix it with `@`. Example: `Console.Write(@"\");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is used as an escape character inside strings. In order to output the `\` itself you need to escape it by doubling it up, or use a string literal by prefixing your string with `@`.

Either of these will work.

```
Console.WriteLine("\\");

Console.WriteLine(@"\");
```

Answer (score 2):

'\' is an escape character.
Use `Console.WriteLine("\\")` to get the desired output. You can also use `@` like
`Console.WriteLine(@"Your_Content")` and the content will be automatically escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's a escape character, use `Console.Write("\\")`. These are used in escape sequences, here is a list of them:

- `\a          →` Bell (alert)
- `\b          →` Backspace
- `\f          →` Formfeed
- `\n          →` New line
- `\r          →` Carriage return
- `\t          →` Horizontal tab
- `\v          →` Vertical tab
- `\'          →` Single quotation mark
- `\"          →` Double quotation mark
- `\\          →` Backslash (You have to use this one)
- `\?          →` Literal question mark
- `\ ooo       →` ASCII character in octal notation
- `\x hh       →` ASCII character in hexadecimal notation
- `\x hhhh     →` Unicode character in hexadecimal notation if this escape sequence is used in a wide-character constant or a Unicode string literal.
- `\uxxxx      →` Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx
- `\xn[n][n][n]→` Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value nnnn (variable length version of \uxxxx)
- `\Uxxxxxxxx  →` Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxxxxxx (for generating surrogates)

You can also use `Console.WriteLine(@"\");`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134547/7237719) for an expanation.