# Trying to make an SQL connection with local database .mdf but I succeed to write the filename directory

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have this line for the connection with my connection string

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C: \Users\BDV\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Interface_notes\Interface_notes\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

But I get this error :

```
Class System.String
Represents Text as a series of Unicode characters
Syntax Error, ',' expected
```

I think the problem is with the double quotation marks, but I can't figure out what I can do instead. Can someone help me with this? Thanks
    Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: [You need `SqlConnection(@"Data Source=...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134547/what-does-the-prefix-do-on-string-literals-in-c) (and you have a stray space after C:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your connection string. One has been already explained to you. This is C# and you need to prefix your string with the verbatim character to avoid parsing error when your string contains a backslash. Also you should remove the double quote around your path. They are not needed here.

The second error is the missing backslash between the (LocalDB) and the instance name.

So you write

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
 AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\BDV\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Project\Interface_notes\
 Interface_notes\Database1.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use verbatim string and remove double quote from inside :

Change it to

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)MSSQLLocalDB;
     AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\BDV\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Project\Interface_notes\
     Interface_notes\Database1.mdf;
     Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
(LocalDB)MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\BDV\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Interface_notes\Interface_notes\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```