# String literal must be prefixed by '@'

Tags: objective-c, swift

I come from JS so I am not sure about string literals.

I have the following syntax in my swift

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"ABCXYZ"];
```

if I remove @ from the above, swift throws the following error `String literal must be prefixed by '@'`

Can someone explain me why I am getting this error and what are string literals? This answer wasn't helpful in above context: [What does the @ prefix do on string literals in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134547/what-does-the-prefix-do-on-string-literals-in-c-sharp)

Comment: That is Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Alright. I don't know native implementation but I am not sure why everyone is down voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **do not post API keys on the Internet**. I have edited your question to remove the key, but it is still visible in the question history.

Anyway, the code you quoted is Objective-C code, not Swift code. That code declares an `NSString` literal. `NSString` is an Objective-C class. In contrast to a plain C string, the `NSString` class provides many APIs for using and manipulating strings, and the Objective-C runtime manages `NSString` memory so you don't have to.

In Swift, the equivalent code is

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("ABCXYZ")
```

Here, we are using a Swift `String` literal, which is similar to `NSString`, with many APIs and with automatic memory management, but we don't need an `@` prefix because Swift is not a superset of C.

Comment: That key contained only a small part of actual key. I mean it won't work for others but thanks for removing it :)

Comment: if I replace `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"ABCXYZ"];` with GMSServices.provideAPIKey("ABCXYZ") in my code. it gives the error `Property 'provideAPIKey' not found on object of type 'GMSServices'`